# How to validate SNMPv3 trap sender authentication/privacy compliance?

Tags: authentication, testing, snmp, snmp4j

Recently I implemented a trap sender using SNMP4J. I have made it configurable so that I can choose between sending SNMPv2 traps OR SNMPv3 traps using NOAUTH_NOPRIV, AUTH_NOPRIV, or AUTH_PRIV security levels. Using powerSNMP Network Manager as the receiver I've been able to verify that traps are being sent and that privacy (encryption) works using DES, 3DES, and AES128.

The problem here is that the powerSNMP manager seems to completely skip the authentication protocol/password check. What I mean by this is that the manager requires the privacy password and protocol to match that of my sender, however; it does not seem to care at all about the correctness of the authentication password or protocol. It simply accepts any message it can decipher. To me this seems strange considering it requires an authentication password/protocol to be entered in conjunction with the privacy password/protocol if privacy is being used.

I've been told that it is the responsibility of the receiver to implement a View Access Control Model (or some subsystem like it) which is responsible for dropping/rejecting unauthenticated messages. With this being the case I can't rule out that there might be an issue with the manager...

What I am really looking for is some good tool(s) or techniques(s) for validating that my sender is attempting to authenticate correctly. I've only recently begun familiarizing with SNMP so if anyone knows of any good resources for testing this I would be very appreciative.

P.S.
I have tried several other large enterprise-scale network managers and have experienced difficulty configuring them with my sender. It seems like they are typically geared toward providing support for more common systems/devices. I am not averse to using something like this, but I would prefer it if someone knew of a more development friendly option at this stage.

Comment: You didn't reveal what exactly is the problem. Messages with wrong authentication or privacy passphrase can still be partially parsed and displayed (if that's what surprised you), and a manager can decide whether to drop such completely or show the partial result. View Access Control Model is for something else.

Comment: The problem is that - if I have written my code correctly (which I believe I have based on the many other examples I've seen) and the manager is not dropping messages when I give it the wrong auth-password or auth-protocol, then how am I supposed to validate my code handles authentication correctly?

Comment: You can build your own SNMP trap receiver/monitor using snmp4j, and then use the pair to test against each other.

Comment: I suppose you're right, and this had crossed my mind, I just hoped that maybe someone out there was familiar with some other tool or manager so that I don't have to wonder if I've coded up a receiver which also could have issues. If nothing else I guess this will be the direction I take.